# How can one show the inequality $\frac{a^2}{\sqrt{b^2-bc+c^2}}+\frac{b^2}{\sqrt{a^2-ac+c^2}}+\frac{c^2}{\sqrt{a^2-ab+b^2}}\ge a+b+c$

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality

How can one show the inequality 
$$\frac{a^2}{\sqrt{b^2-bc+c^2}}+\frac{b^2}{\sqrt{a^2-ac+c^2}}+\frac{c^2}{\sqrt{a^2-ab+b^2}}\ge a+b+c$$

Where $a,b,c$ are real and $ab+bc+ac$ is no equal to zero

This is what I did:

By Cauchy we have: 
$$\frac{a^2}{\sqrt{b^2-bc+c^2}}+\frac{b^2}{\sqrt{a^2-ac+c^2}}+\frac{c^2}{\sqrt{a^2-ab+b^2}}\ge\frac{(a+b+c)^2}{\sqrt{b^2-bc+c^2}+{\sqrt{a^2-ac+c^2}}+{\sqrt{a^2-ab+b^2}}}$$

So I need to prove that $${\sqrt{b^2-bc+c^2}+{\sqrt{a^2-ac+c^2}}+{\sqrt{a^2-ab+b^2}}}\ge(a+b+c)$$

We see that for example $b^2-bc+c^2=(b-c)^2+bc$

I still stuck here!

Comment: Should the last equality be $b^2-bc+c^2=(b-c)^2+bc$? Unless, it is implied $b=0$ or $c=0$.

Comment: What do you mean by "no null"? And isn't $a=b=c=1$ a counterexample?

Comment: Actually you need to prove the denominator is $\le a+b+c$ to conclude, which is evidently wrong. This approach as it is currently hence does not work.

Comment: $${\sqrt{b^2-bc+c^2}+{\sqrt{a^2-ac+c^2}}+{\sqrt{a^2-ab+b^2}}}\ge(a+b+c)$$ **does not imply** $$\frac{(a+b+c)^2}{\sqrt{b^2-bc+c^2}+{\sqrt{a^2-ac+c^2}}+{\sqrt{a^2-ab+b^2}}} \ge a+b+c$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint

Use Holder inequality:
$$\left(\sum_{cyc}\dfrac{a^2}{\sqrt{b^2-bc+c^2}}\right)^2\left(\sum_{cyc}a^2(b^2-bc+c^2)\right)\ge (a^2+b^2+c^2)^3$$
so we need prove to
$$(a^2+b^2+c^2)^3\ge (a+b+c)^2\sum_{cyc}a^2(b^2-bc+c^2)$$
This is not hard to prove it.

Comment: Your approach is of course the right one, the other answer does not lead anywhere. +1

Comment: What do you mean by sum cyc ?

Answer (score 2):

Note that:
$3(a-b)^{2}\ge0$

hence $4a^{2}-4ab+4b^{2}\ge a^{2}+b^{2}+2ab$.

And so:

$a^{2}-ab+b^{2}\ge\frac{a^{2}+b^{2}+2ab}{4}$

Since both sides are positive:

$\sqrt{a^{2}-ab+b^{2}}\ge\sqrt{\frac{a^{2}+b^{2}+2ab}{4}}$

We can do the same for each of $a,c$ and $b,c$ leading us to conclude that,

$\sqrt{b^{2}-bc+c^{2}}+\sqrt{a^{2}-ac+c^{2}}+\sqrt{a^{2}-ab+b^{2}}\ge\sqrt{\frac{(b^{2}+2bc+c^{2})}{4}}+\sqrt{\frac{(a^{2}+2ac+c^{2})}{4}}+\sqrt{\frac{(b^{2}+2ba+a^{2})}{4}}=\frac{a+b}{2}+\frac{a+c}{2}+\frac{b+c}{2}=a+b+c$

Comment: While I do not down vote, this step does nothing to prove the orginal inequality problem, I hope you realise.  It seems the OP has still not figured out his approach is wrong.

Comment: I'm sorry I did not realise that.